# Is the maximum value really integral??

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, optimization

Let $f(x)$ be defines as : $$f(x)=\tan^{-1}\left(\dfrac{(\sqrt{12}-2)x^2}{x^4+2x^2+3}\right)$$
and $m$ and $M$ be defined as minimum and maximum values of $f(x)$ and $x=a(a>0)$ is a point in the domain of $f(x)$ where $f(x)$ attains the maximum value.

My question is that i want to confirm the values of $m$ and $M$. $m$ simply comes out to be $0$ while $M$ is a bit debatable. I'm getting $M=\tan^{-1}(2-\sqrt{3})$

I tried the standard method of diffrentiating and putting $f'(x)=0$ and finding the critical points but I want someone to **confirm this one**. Thanx!

Note: My final quadratic equation for $f'(x)=0$ came out to be: $$4(\sqrt{3}-1)(3-x^4)x=0$$
and considered critical points to be $x=0,x^2=\sqrt{3}$ .

Comment: Whatever $M$ is, it's definitely not debatable.

Comment: @MattSamuel Good point though.

Comment: [Wolfram Alpha](https://goo.gl/VN2UOk) agrees with you.  $\tan^{-1}(2-\sqrt{3}) = \frac{\pi}{12}$.

Comment: And that $\frac{\pi}{12} $ just setteled the dust. thank you @MatthewLeingang

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, arctan is a monotonic function so we can find the $x_{max}$ for:
$$g(x) = \frac{bx^2}{x^4+2x^2+3}$$
$$g'(x) = \frac{2bx(x^4+2x^2+3)-bx^2(4x^3+4x)}{(\cdots)^2} = 0$$
$$2bx(x^4+2x^2+3)-bx^2(4x^3+4x) = 0$$
We remember that $x=0$ is a solution and is a minimum point so we are looking for solutions $x\neq0$. Hence we can divide by $bx$:
$$2(x^4+2x^2+3)-x(4x^3+4x) =0$$
$$2x^4+4x^2+6-4x^4-4x^2=0$$
$$2x^4=6$$
$$x^4 = 3$$
$$x^2= \sqrt{3}$$
so
$$g(x_{max}) = \frac{b\sqrt{3}}{3+2\sqrt{3}+3} = \frac{6-2\sqrt{3}}{6+2\sqrt{3}}$$
So
$$f(x_{max}) = \arctan(g(x_{max})) = \frac{\pi}{12}$$